# Move files into an existing folder in GitHub

Tags: github, directory-structure

I want to move my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files into the `sortable-list` folder.

[image: screenshot of my github repo]

I intended to push the files of my **sortable-list** project into a folder named `sortable-list` in my **javascript-projects** repository. However, when I pushed the files using the cli, it added all the files directly to my `zaidazim/javascript-projects` repo.

I wish to move the files into the sortable-list folder, so that in the future I can add more project folders here.

How can I achieve that?

P.S.~ I've read some of the previously asked questions but they haven't really helped me much.

Comment: Move the files to the target folder and re-commit? Honestly, it’s not at all clear what you’ve tried, where you’re getting stuck, or why simply moving these files to match the desired directory structure doesn’t meet your requirements.

Comment: Pardon me if I wasn't clear with my question. The files in the above screenshot viz., index.html, style.css, script.js, are part of the sortable-list project(a mini project I made using HTML, CSS, and javascript). Now I created the sortable-list directory using the add file option and simply want those files inside that created directory. Hopefully! that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that repository cloned locally, simply use [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

```
cd /path/to/repo
git mv script.js  sortable-list
git commit -m "move file"
git push
```